# Create a bat file to encrypt and decrypt (RSA) web config

Tags: rsa, batch-file, encryption

Can anyone show me how to create a bat file that will encrypt and decrypt a web config
What I want it to do is open up the Visual Studios 2010 Command Prompt start in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\" and Run the following for Decrypt.
aspnet_regiis -pdf "appSettings" "C:\Development Projects\Web Applications\projectName"
then the bat file close

If you can show me how to do one I can do the other. I am just not sure how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your specific command requirements, but what problems are you experiencing?

```
@ECHO OFF
CD "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\"
aspnet_regiis -pdf "appSettings" "C:\Development Projects\Web Applications\projectName"
```

That will do what you describe, unless there's something peculiar about aspnet_regiis.

Comment: I know its been too late but for others, Please check below link with same requirement 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/configuration-file-decryption-and-encryption-using-batch-file